# How would I turn an open telnet shell into a Metasploit session?

Tags: metasploit, metasploitable

I'm trying to pivot using a metasploitable2 system, which has a shell port open in a scan:

`port       status   service
 1524/tcp   open     shell`

Accessing the root shell is easy enough in telnet, or even using `connect` in msfconsole but this does not create a session which i can use with meterpreter or routing options.

Does anybody know any options such as metasploit modules that exploit an open shell port? A seemingly trivial "exploit" but hard to find one..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `root` on the server (or any kind of shell access), generate a payload on Metasploit, copy it to the server, and execute.

You don't turn telnet into meterpreter, you start another connection.

Comment: thanks for your answer! how would i generate such a payload for a linux system? would i use msfvenom?

Comment: Yes, `msfvenom` is the tool you need. On https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/How-to-use-msfvenom you can have some examples.